# The collection of open intervals is not a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We need to show that the collection of open intervals is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

For it to be a $\sigma$-algebra, we need to show that $\emptyset, \Omega$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra, which it is.

However, I believe that it doesn't have complements. But I am not sure how to justify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not closed under union: $(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ is not an open interval.

It's not closed under complement: $\Bbb R \setminus (0,1)$ is not an open interval.